# How to add days and minutes to datetime objects in R?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I am trying to parse a datetime like this: `14.08.2014 00:00:01.202`

I'm trying to get the following formation:

1. What day of the week it is
2. Add n minutes to the datetime
3. Add n days for the datetime

Being new to R, I understand there are a few packages that deal with time. Right now, based on my research and level of skill, I'm studying the `lubridate` package to try and accomplish these tasks. I'm running into difficulties because of the milliseconds (I think).

Can someone give me an example of the code I would need to accomplish these tasks?

Comment: No need in external packages. Check `?strptime`. Or do some Google search

Comment: My question was answered perfectly the first time. This implies I phrased it correctly and posted it in the right place... (humbly) I question the logic of this "put on hold..." mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert to `POSIXct` Type

```
MyDate <- as.POSIXct("14.08.2014 00:00:01.202", format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
MyDate
## [1] "2014-08-14 00:00:01 IDT"
```

Week day

```
format(as.Date(MyDate), "%w") # Weekday as decimal number (0–6, Sunday is 0).
## [1] "3"
```

Or

```
format(as.Date(MyDate), "%u") # Weekday as a decimal number (1–7, Monday is 1).
## [1] "3"
```

Add minute

```
MyDate + 60
## [1] "2014-08-14 00:01:01 IDT"
```

Add hour

```
MyDate + 3600
## [1] "2014-08-14 01:00:01 IDT"
```

Comment: killer <- ThanksDavid() !!!

Comment: works like a charm! Thanks for saving me hours!!!

Comment: NP, I'm sure Google could offer some help too